# Is it possible to exclude certain data from an array when using the map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that the map function is used to render a list of data of an array to the DOM, but I was wondering if it is possible to exclude some data so that it doesn't render to the DOM?

[image: Here's an image of my issue]

Trying to display 1 button per page instead of 6 buttons on one page. This is what I have for my code:

The Code I'm using to render the CartButton onto the page:

```html
import React from 'react'
import '../css/product.css'
import Reviews from './review'
import prodArray from './productArray'
import Cart from './Cart'
import CartButton from './CartButton'
// import addtoFavorite from ''


class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
    // console.log(props.toString())
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.id,
      currentProduct: prodArray,
      cartItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')): [],
    }
  }

  createOrder = (order) => {
    alert("Need to save order for " + order.name )
}

removeFromCart = (product) => {
    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
    this.setState({cartItems: cartItems.filter(x=>x.id !== product.id)})
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(this.state.cartItems));
}

addToCart = (product) => {
    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
    let isInCart = false;
    cartItems.forEach(item => {
        if(item.id === product.id) {
            item.count++;
            isInCart = true;
        }
    });
    if(!isInCart) {
        cartItems.push({...product, count: 1})
    }
    this.setState({cartItems});
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='product'>
        <h1>PC: {prodArray[this.state.id].name}</h1>
        <img src={prodArray[this.state.id].imageUrl} alt={prodArray[this.state.id].imageAlt} className='plantImage' />
        <h2>PC: {prodArray[this.state.id].price}</h2>
        {
          prodArray[this.state.id].description.map( ( indDesc ) => {
            return <li>{indDesc}</li>
          } )
        }
        <CartButton products={this.state.products} addToCart={this.addToCart}></CartButton>
        <Cart cartItems={this.state.cartItems} removeFromCart = {this.removeFromCart}/>
        {/* component to change isFavorite -> True */}
        {/* <Favorite id={this.state.id} /> */}
        <p hidden>NOTE: Bottom 3 no-show on Home</p>
        <br />
        <Reviews />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Product
```

CartButton:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import prodArray from './productArray'

class CartButton extends Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props )
        // console.log(props.toString())
        this.state = {
          id: this.props.id,
        }
      }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul className='products'>
                    {prodArray?.map( (product) => (
                        <div key={prodArray[this.state.id]}>
                            <button onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(product)} className='button primary'>Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CartButton;
```

The Array that I'm using:

```html
let productArray = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Plant Pots 1',
    description: [
      'Indoor & Outdoor Use: A simple modern aesthetic and clean matte finish planters indoor plants will perfectly match any home or office décor. it can bear extreme temperature environment and is suitable for indoor and outdoor . With better breathabiity and water absorption, it\'s beneficial to the healthy growth of plants.',
      'Practical Set of 2:This set features 2 pieces, 8 inch in diameter each.Planters are lightweight and easy-to-handle.The indoor & outdoor planters sizes fit nearly all small to medium-sized indoor house plants and herb spice gardens. Works well with orchid, cactus, succulents, aloe vera, basil, flowers, Peace Lily, air plants, snake plant.',
      'Easy draim holses Movable tray:Excess water flows out the dual drainage holes to prevent overwatering and flooding. Plates capture overflow water for easy cleanup. It is recommended to shop a layer of filler in the bottom of the flower pot.',
      'Environmental Material:Made of durable recyclable plastic,solid plastic plant pots protect plants and soil. Premium polypropylene planters feel sturdy in hand but not too heavy. Thick sidewalls from 2mm to 3mm in size keep everything in place.',
      'Perfect shopping experience:We aim to improve planting experience. Guarantee the quality of the product is our responsibility. If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us.'
    ],
    price: 19.99,
    imageUrl: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71smkmbWsgL._AC_SL1500_.jpg',
    imageAlt: '2 plant pots',
    isInCart: false,
    isFavorite: false,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Plant Pots 2',
    description: [
      'Indoor & Outdoor Use: A simple modern aesthetic and clean matte finish planters indoor plants will perfectly match any home or office décor. it can bear extreme temperature environment and is suitable for indoor and outdoor . With better breathabiity and water absorption, it\'s beneficial to the healthy growth of plants.',
      'Practical Set of 2:This set features 2 pieces, 8 inch in diameter each.Planters are lightweight and easy-to-handle.The indoor & outdoor planters sizes fit nearly all small to medium-sized indoor house plants and herb spice gardens. Works well with orchid, cactus, succulents, aloe vera, basil, flowers, Peace Lily, air plants, snake plant.',
      'Easy draim holses Movable tray:Excess water flows out the dual drainage holes to prevent overwatering and flooding. Plates capture overflow water for easy cleanup. It is recommended to shop a layer of filler in the bottom of the flower pot.',
      'Environmental Material:Made of durable recyclable plastic,solid plastic plant pots protect plants and soil. Premium polypropylene planters feel sturdy in hand but not too heavy. Thick sidewalls from 2mm to 3mm in size keep everything in place.',
      'Perfect shopping experience:We aim to improve planting experience. Guarantee the quality of the product is our responsibility. If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us.'
    ],
    price: 19.99,
    imageUrl: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71smkmbWsgL._AC_SL1500_.jpg',
    imageAlt: '2 plant pots',
    isInCart: false,
    isFavorite: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Plant Pots 3',
    description: [
      'Indoor & Outdoor Use: A simple modern aesthetic and clean matte finish planters indoor plants will perfectly match any home or office décor. it can bear extreme temperature environment and is suitable for indoor and outdoor . With better breathabiity and water absorption, it\'s beneficial to the healthy growth of plants.',
      'Practical Set of 2:This set features 2 pieces, 8 inch in diameter each.Planters are lightweight and easy-to-handle.The indoor & outdoor planters sizes fit nearly all small to medium-sized indoor house plants and herb spice gardens. Works well with orchid, cactus, succulents, aloe vera, basil, flowers, Peace Lily, air plants, snake plant.',
      'Easy draim holses Movable tray:Excess water flows out the dual drainage holes to prevent overwatering and flooding. Plates capture overflow water for easy cleanup. It is recommended to shop a layer of filler in the bottom of the flower pot.',
      'Environmental Material:Made of durable recyclable plastic,solid plastic plant pots protect plants and soil. Premium polypropylene planters feel sturdy in hand but not too heavy. Thick sidewalls from 2mm to 3mm in size keep everything in place.',
      'Perfect shopping experience:We aim to improve planting experience. Guarantee the quality of the product is our responsibility. If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us.'
    ],
    price: 19.99,
    imageUrl: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71smkmbWsgL._AC_SL1500_.jpg',
    imageAlt: '2 plant pots',
    isInCart: false,
    isFavorite: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Plant Pots 4',
    description: [
      'Indoor & Outdoor Use: A simple modern aesthetic and clean matte finish planters indoor plants will perfectly match any home or office décor. it can bear extreme temperature environment and is suitable for indoor and outdoor . With better breathabiity and water absorption, it\'s beneficial to the healthy growth of plants.',
      'Practical Set of 2:This set features 2 pieces, 8 inch in diameter each.Planters are lightweight and easy-to-handle.The indoor & outdoor planters sizes fit nearly all small to medium-sized indoor house plants and herb spice gardens. Works well with orchid, cactus, succulents, aloe vera, basil, flowers, Peace Lily, air plants, snake plant.',
      'Easy draim holses Movable tray:Excess water flows out the dual drainage holes to prevent overwatering and flooding. Plates capture overflow water for easy cleanup. It is recommended to shop a layer of filler in the bottom of the flower pot.',
      'Environmental Material:Made of durable recyclable plastic,solid plastic plant pots protect plants and soil. Premium polypropylene planters feel sturdy in hand but not too heavy. Thick sidewalls from 2mm to 3mm in size keep everything in place.',
      'Perfect shopping experience:We aim to improve planting experience. Guarantee the quality of the product is our responsibility. If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us.'
    ],
    price: 19.99,
    imageUrl: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71smkmbWsgL._AC_SL1500_.jpg',
    imageAlt: '2 plant pots',
    isInCart: false,
    isFavorite: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Plant Pots 5',
    description: [
      'Indoor & Outdoor Use: A simple modern aesthetic and clean matte finish planters indoor plants will perfectly match any home or office décor. it can bear extreme temperature environment and is suitable for indoor and outdoor . With better breathabiity and water absorption, it\'s beneficial to the healthy growth of plants.',
      'Practical Set of 2:This set features 2 pieces, 8 inch in diameter each.Planters are lightweight and easy-to-handle.The indoor & outdoor planters sizes fit nearly all small to medium-sized indoor house plants and herb spice gardens. Works well with orchid, cactus, succulents, aloe vera, basil, flowers, Peace Lily, air plants, snake plant.',
      'Easy draim holses Movable tray:Excess water flows out the dual drainage holes to prevent overwatering and flooding. Plates capture overflow water for easy cleanup. It is recommended to shop a layer of filler in the bottom of the flower pot.',
      'Environmental Material:Made of durable recyclable plastic,solid plastic plant pots protect plants and soil. Premium polypropylene planters feel sturdy in hand but not too heavy. Thick sidewalls from 2mm to 3mm in size keep everything in place.',
      'Perfect shopping experience:We aim to improve planting experience. Guarantee the quality of the product is our responsibility. If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us.'
    ],
    price: 19.99,
    imageUrl: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71smkmbWsgL._AC_SL1500_.jpg',
    imageAlt: '2 plant pots',
    isInCart: false,
    isFavorite: false
  }
]

export default productArray
```

Comment: I would use `filter()` to exclude items, then `map()`.

Comment: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the data from state first to get rid of elements you don't want, and then render that array with `map`.

Comment: Would it be possible to filter out buttons? I'm having an issue with a project where 6 buttons are showing on a page, but I only want to display one button for each page.

Comment: Post the code you've got so far and we can get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just updated my question with my code and image!

Comment: I'm not seeing an array of buttons? But the concept is the same - `filter()` to weed out what you don't want, then render as usual.

Comment: My apologizes. I think the map function is rendering the number of ids there are in the array, which makes me think that there are 6 buttons in the array that are displayed in the picture above.

Comment: To which map function are you referring? I'm not seeing it in your code.

Comment: My apologizes again. I was messing around with my code to see if I can fix the issue I'm having. the map function was where the forEach function used to be in the CartButton code. I updated the code to replace forEach with map.

Comment: I think most of the problem is that you're not treating `CartButton` as a dumb component. Instead, for some reason, you're importing all of your data into it, and then rendering all of it.. You should be passing only the information (as props) to it that it needs from the parent component.